# How Can I Download An Image From A Website In Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to be able to scrape the image from a website such as the example below where my intention would be to scrape the image of the player and store that in a temp file so that I could display it in a Tkinter window.

https://www.futbin.com/22/player/573/trent-alexander-arnold

I have come across multiple users using BeautifulSoup so any help regarding that would be greatly appreciated.

This is some sample code that I found and have slightly adapted:

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os
 
# CREATE FOLDER
def folder_create(images):
    try:
        folder_name = input("Enter Folder Name:- ")
        # folder creation
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
 
    # if folder exists with that name, ask another name
    except:
        print("Folder Exist with that name!")
        folder_create()
 
    # image downloading start
    download_images(images, folder_name)
 
 
# DOWNLOAD ALL IMAGES FROM THAT URL
def download_images(images, folder_name):
   
    # initial count is zero
    count = 0
 
    # print total images found in URL
    print(f"Total {len(images)} Image Found!")
 
    # checking if images is not zero
    if len(images) != 0:
        for i, image in enumerate(images):
            # From image tag ,Fetch image Source URL
 
                        # 1.data-srcset
                        # 2.data-src
                        # 3.data-fallback-src
                        # 4.src
 
            # Here we will use exception handling
 
            # first we will search for "data-srcset" in img tag
            try:
                # In image tag ,searching for "data-srcset"
                image_link = image["data-srcset"]
                 
            # then we will search for "data-src" in img
            # tag and so on..
            except:
                try:
                    # In image tag ,searching for "data-src"
                    image_link = image["data-src"]
                except:
                    try:
                        # In image tag ,searching for "data-fallback-src"
                        image_link = image["data-fallback-src"]
                    except:
                        try:
                            # In image tag ,searching for "src"
                            image_link = image["src"]
 
                        # if no Source URL found
                        except:
                            pass
 
            # After getting Image Source URL
            # We will try to get the content of image
            try:
                r = requests.get(image_link).content
                try:
 
                    # possibility of decode
                    r = str(r, 'utf-8')
 
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
 
                    # After checking above condition, Image Download start
                    with open(f"{folder_name}/images{i+1}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
                        f.write(r)
 
                    # counting number of image downloaded
                    count += 1
            except:
                pass
 
        # There might be possible, that all
        # images not download
        # if all images download
        if count == len(images):
            print("All Images Downloaded!")
             
        # if all images not download
        else:
            print(f"Total {count} Images Downloaded Out of {len(images)}")
 
# MAIN FUNCTION START
def main(url):
   
    # content of URL
    r = requests.get(url)
 
    # Parse HTML Code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
 
    # find all images in URL
    images = soup.findAll('img')

    folder_name = input("Enter Folder Name:- ")

    download_images(images, folder_name)
 
    # Call folder create function
    try:
        folder_create(images)
    except:
        x = 0
 
# take url
url = input("Enter URL:- ")
 
# CALL MAIN FUNCTION
main(url)
```

This code runs, however it does not seem to find the image file at all. I am also aware this scrapes all images. This code also works on other websites I have tested such as https://www.premierleague.com/players/4852/Adri%C3%A1n/overview

Comment: Did you know, you dont have to download the image just to show in the tkinter window?

Comment: Futbin uses CloudFlare to protect it from scraping... I've had more success with Futwiz

Comment: @CoolCloud I didn't would you be able to expand on that?

Comment: @bushcat69 my program relies on futbin at it also scrapes the price from there, I guess I could switch it over to Futwiz, would just be annoying haha

Comment: @CoolCloud would you have any knowledge of embedding a web browser into a tkinter window?

Comment: @bushcat69 would you have any knowledge of embedding a web browser into a tkinter window?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```py
urls = [img.get('src', None) for img in soup.findAll('img')]
```

to get a list of image links, then do your download/save commands like

```py
for url in urls:
    if url:
        save_image(url, folder_name)
```

Note: It seems like you're using BeautifulSoup v3 because of the `findAll()` method. If you use BeautifulSoup v4 use `find_all()`.